# Header DDL in Gridview on ispostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback, rowdatabound

I have a header DDL in my gridview that for some reason does not keep my selected value but rather binds the gridview and the header back to "***starting position***"

In my DDL header for **Priority** i have selected value '99' but after that my header gets back to starting position of my `ListItem` (that is Priority)

[image]

[image]

```
    <HeaderTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPriorityHeader" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlHeader_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
                                 <asp:ListItem>Priority</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
```

I have a `RowDatabound` for the gridview but there i do nothing more then find the DDL for the header and then bound the DDL.

```
protected void gwActivity_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //.............. some code.....//

 string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  DISTINCT [Priority] FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblPriority]", con);
                    con.Open();
                    ddlPriority.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ddlPriority.DataTextField = "Priority";
                    ddlPriority.DataBind();
                }

}
```

I have put my `gridview` in a method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridviewActivity();
    }
}
```

Can it be that im bounding my DDL everytime for my gridview? im stuck here....

Comment: Why are you binding DDL on every rowDataBound? bind it only once.

Comment: I do not know exactly what you mean?. Do you mean why i bound my DDL on gwActivity_RowDataBound()... then hmm how would do it only for my DDL?

Comment: should i create a RowDataBound for each DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store `ddlPriority` selected text in temp place like `ViewState` that will keep value between postbacks.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["PriorityText"] = "Priority";
        BindGridviewActivity();
    }
}
```

And aftrt `ddlPriority.DataBind();` set selectd text to `ViewState` value

```
ddlPriority.Items.FindByText(ViewState["PriorityText"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

And in your `ddlHeader_SelectedIndexChanged` set `ViewState` to selected text

```
protected void ddlHeader_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlHeader = (DropDownList)sender;
    ViewState["PriorityText"] = ddlHeader.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Check this [complete example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Excel-like-AutoFilter-Feature-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control.aspx) for more details

Comment: Hi thank you. What i did is set  ViewState["PriorityText"] = "Priority"; in page load BEOFRE BindGridviewActivity() and in my gwActivity_RowDataBoun() AFTER  ddlPriority.DataBind() i put ddlPriority.Items.FindByText(ViewState["PriorityText"].ToString()).Selected = true. But this still did not work

Comment: The gridview filters but the DDL control(s) still get back to the default ListITem

Comment: You need also to set view state value in  `ddlHeader_SelectedIndexChanged`, Check updated answer

Comment: Thank you, What is "Filter" representing?

Comment: Should it be ViewState["PriorityText"] = ddlHeader.selectedITem.text; ?

Comment: Sorry, its "PriorityText"

Comment: However this will only work for my first page of my gridview. do you know how to do this with PageIndexChanging in mind?

Comment: Check this [complete example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Excel-like-AutoFilter-Feature-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control.aspx)